# Create legend for subsets of a bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to create a legend for the folowing plot and marginals? I searched trough `?theme` but I get no idea.

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4), col2 = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1), z = rnorm(6))

p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(col1, y = ..count..,fill=col2))
p1 <- p1 + geom_bar()

p2 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = z))
p2<-p2 + geom_density()
p2

gt1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))
gt2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p2))
```

Get maximum widths and heights for x-axis and y-axis title and text

```
maxWidth = unit.pmax(gt1$widths[2:3], gt2$widths[2:3])
```

Set the maximums in the gtables for gt1, gt2 and gt3

```
gt1$widths[2:3] <- as.list(maxWidth)
gt2$widths[2:3] <- as.list(maxWidth)
```

Combine the scatterplot with the two marginal boxplots
Create a new gtable

```
gt <- gtable(widths = unit(c(7, 2), "null"), height = unit(c(2, 7), "null"))
```

Instert gt1, gt2 and gt3 into the new gtable

```
gt <- gtable_add_grob(gt, gt1, 2, 1)
gt <- gtable_add_grob(gt, gt2, 1, 1)
```

And render the plot

```
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt)
```

Comment: Sorry for the offtopic, but why do you use for loop in the first plot? You could add group=col2,fill="blue" or fill=col2 (different colors for each id). Think doing loop will take more time

Comment: @Asayat I add it, because I thougth it has relevance for the question. Think about some function where you want to use this mechanism and want to add a legend. But for now I edit the start post.

Comment: I ask it,bz it give a bit diff results and I didn't understand why doing that. It will be just great if you could show what plot you have now and what plot do you want(or at least explain what legends you expect). When you do the loop, the result is a bit differ than in filter,as col2 categories overlay in each other, making some regions darker. While in fill it's just one on top of another. So do you want a legend for each plot color, like when fill, say, col2 =1 is red, col2 =2 is blue or on previuos plot 1 id is light, 2 ids is darker?

Comment: All I wanted to say is your plot depends on what you trying to say. In your initial post your plot showed that regions where both col2 categories are used are darker, than those where only 1 was used, not showing which id it is. Got it? When you use fill, it's a diff plot, with id's laying one on top of another (or behind each other, if you use position="dodge"). What legends you want?

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clear.
Your initial code with a loop produced slightly diff result, than a fill option

1) If you want to add legend, you should add colors to ***mapping***:

```
ggplot(data,aes(col1,group=col2,fill="id"))+
geom_bar(position="identity",alpha=0.5)+
scale_fill_manual(name="id",values="blue")
```

[image]

If you have bigger data, you can't add each overlayed color to the legend, as there will be many options. The darkness of the each bar shows how intense each col1 with col2 ids, but doesn't show with which one

2) The "fill" option is a bit different

```
ggplot(data,aes(col1,fill=as.factor(col2)))+geom_bar(position="dodge")
```

[image]

It just shows col2 ids for each col1. The idea is slightly different.

3) You can change legend manually by adding:

```
guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Col2",
                       direction = "vertical",title.position="top",
                       title.vjust = 0.5)) # just example
```

And legend keys by using scale_fill_discrete() option

4) Not sure what kind of legend you want for the density plot, but let's assume like this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = z,colour="id"))+ 
geom_density()+
scale_colour_manual(name="id",values="blue")
```

[image]

And then you just add plots together. By the way, check [this](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_%28ggplot2%29/) tutorial for adding multiple plots together, hope you find it useful :)

P.S. you can mix fill=col2, position="identity" and alpha=0.5, that will be just an awful plot that's hard to be explained, and no scale brewer can help :)

[image]

UPD: Using gtable as in your code.
Let example 1 be p1 plot, and example 4 be p2.
After simply copy-pasting your code, you'll get the following:
[image]

If you had a look at the tutorial I mentioned, you could get the following:
[image]

Again, please **clarify** what you really want to do with legends. When you get the size of the plot, you the plot includes the legend too.

If you could simply at least try the examples I showed, you could see the differences in your ggtables. Legend goes as `guide-box` (as you could guess by the option used to edit the legend). So, you asked how to create legends - ta-da. Where's legends in the ggtable? ta-da. If you still have other problems, I'm afraid that they're beyond SO competence

Comment: @Asyat, many thx, but the problem is a little more complicated, if you can see, I use ggplot_table, to combine two plots. So my question is related to the point how  to manage the legend for this table.

Comment: Well, you haven't asked that way, and haven't replied to comments neither, so I was just confused. I highly recommend you to edit your post, so ppl could know, not guess, what you're looking for. As for multiple plots, I've shown a link, hope it will be useful.

Comment: And I still haven't understood what you're up to. When you use ggtable, it takes all plot, **including** the legends. So when you _create_ a legend, as you asked, it **will** be in your final plot after using gtable anyway. If you have some other question, please clarify